# How to know properties of ion Aluminum -27?

Tags: ions

How do I know the charge/properties of this Ion Aluminum -27? All the information given is that Al has an atomic number of 13. I want to know how to know that it has an electric charge of +3 from the given information.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. If you mean aluminum-27 not *aluminum -27* then it's not relevant to its electric charge. $\ce{^27Al}$ can have +1, +2, +3 etc. positive charges depending on how much energy you provide.

Comment: The $\ce{Al^2^7-}$ ion will be extremely reducing. You probably need to keep it in vacuum fixed to the negative pole of your stabilised DC wiring. However, it should make for very impressive lightning. Was that not the question you asked?

Comment: Given that a -2 ion will auto-ionize extremely quickly back to -1, he must mean the isotope, not the charge state.

Answer (score 1):

[Aluminum-27](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aluminium#Isotopes) refers to an isotope of aluminum. For almost all chemical reactions the isotope makes no difference in the chemistry. You need "exotic" (meaning very unusual) conditions for the isotope to matter.

Unusual conditions would mostly happen in the gas state. For example a lighter gas would diffuse faster. This was the basis for the separation of uranium isotopes at Oak Ridge during WWII to make the first atomic bomb.

Comment: The main isotope separation mechanism at Oak Ridge during the war were the Calutrons doing magnetic separation on an ion beam. Liquid diffusion, developed at the Naval Research Lab started to be used late in the war early in the process to make slightly enriched feedstock for the Calutrons. Gas diffusion was developed post-war.

Answer (score 0):

For this you must know about noble elements like Helium, Neon,Argon,etc.

When elements except those I have mentioned above want to become stable they tend to form ions.

In order to solve your question, you must know the nearest noble gas to aluminum, which is neon with atomic number 10.

Aluminium atom naturally 13 protons and electrons each and it has to donate its 3 electrons to become like neon.

When it donates 3 electrons, the number of protons become more and hence positive 3 charge.

Comment: Did you understand the question, since I didn't. But if I understand correctly what you're getting at, Al can form ions of whatever charge it wants. It's just that its most common oxidation state in Al compounds is +3. Careful what your choice of words are.